# php in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

The javascript works fine without the php part but it needs to redirect and keep the link information how to do this ??

```
<script>
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1)
{
   window.location = "demo2.php?skin=<?php echo $_GET["skin"]; ?>";
}
</script>
```

works :

```
<script>
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1)
{
   window.location = "demo2.php?skin=<?php echo $_GET['skin']; ?>";
}
</script>
```

Comment: How is it not working?  When you include the PHP code, what gets rendered to the browser?

Comment: What is the URL of the page you're on? Are you sure the page has a query string with skin set? (`?skin=something`? What does `var_dump($_GET)` say?

Comment: Would be good to know what get's output. Do you get a PHP error or is it just that $_GET["skin"] is empty. If it's the latter the error might be elsewhere

Comment: @johana, what you have should work fine.  If it isn't, then something outside of the code you have shown us is incorrect.  In any case, you need to be escaping what you have in `$_GET['skin']` to avoid XSS troubles.

Comment: @johana, Your last edit doesn't make any sense.  Show us the full code.

Comment: @Brad is correct: How is it that `$_GET["skin"];` doesn't work but `$_GET['skin'];` does? I have a strong feeling we don't have all the information here...

Comment: @johana Please follow up on your question and tell us if you have found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

window.location is an object, and assigning a string to an object doesn't bode well for readability or maintenance even though it might work just perfectly.

use window.location.href instead.

Your code is correct, I just tested it and it works fine. In order to replicate your issue, would you please add your code in JSFiddle and see how to goes. If the problem persists, post the fiddle here and let us take a look.

```
     <?
       $skin = prepare($_GET['skin']);//escape your string etc
    ?>
<script>
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") !== -1)//note the two == 
    {   //use href as location reference. 
        window.location.href = "demo2.php?skin=<?php echo $skin; ?>";//access variable instead of global $_GET directly
    }
</script>
```

As for your question:

1. (works fine without the php part) what goes wrong with php part
   then?
2. (but it needs to redirect and keep the link information)
   what information?

I'm sorry but those points are not clear for me: 
Does it redirect when Firefox is in use? if so, does it redirect to the correct page with the expected url? or it troughs an error? if so who's throwing the error, php or js?

**n.b: Since your issue is with qoutation, are you placing the whole JS block in PHP string?**

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<script>
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1)
{
    window.location = "demo2.php?skin=<?php echo $_GET['skin']; ?>";
}
</script>
```

There was an error because you use double quote " instead of single quote ', so the string ended at "demo2.php?skin=

Comment: How is this any different than his example?

Comment: you are wrong, it makes no difference.  PHP doesn't care that you used quotes outside of what it parses.

Comment: @Brad In this code, PHP does not perform variable interpolation in the `skin` string. That's the only difference I could spot.

Comment: -1 for `There was an error because you use double quote " instead of single quote ', so the string ended at "demo2.php?skin=`, that's completely incorrect, the `"` mark was inside a `<?php` tag and does *not* get output to the HTML code and *does not* end the JavaScript string.

Comment: My mistake. I really thought what I said, but it was a big error! Thanks for the explanation :-).
But the question now is, why does it work with "GET['']" and not with "GET_[""]"?

Comment: @MarcoPace, It doesn't.  Johana changed something else, or there are missing details (such as funky characters in `$_GET['skin']`).  In any case, you should delete your answer so that others don't get confused.